# Determine if two dates are within an allowed time span

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I got a `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` that I have to *validate*.
For them to be valid they have to be *within allowed hours* which are fully customizable.

```
// allowed hours
allowedStart = new TimeSpan(08, 00, 0);
allowedEnd   = new TimeSpan(20, 00, 0);
```

Now the two dates (`StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`) are coming in (some example test cases)

```
    // Valid date
    obj1.StartDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 10, 0);
    obj1.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 20, 0);

    // End date exceeding
    obj2.StartDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 50, 0);
    obj2.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 15, 0);

    // Start and end date exceeding
    obj3.StartDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 10, 0);
    obj3.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 35, 0);

    // Invalid (overnight) both exceeding
    obj4.StartDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 23, 50, 0);
    obj4.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 31, 0, 35, 0);

    // Start to early
    obj5.StartDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 31, 7, 50, 0);
    obj5.EndDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 1, 31, 8, 15, 0);
```

I was wondering if there isn't some *already implemented function* I haven't found since my brain is dying right now. I've been trying to implement this myself like this but the `obj4` testcase *still kills it*:

```
    if ((obj.StartDateTime.Date.Add(allowedStart) <= obj.StartDateTime) &&
        (allowedEnd < allowedStart 
           ? obj.EndDateTime <= obj.EndDateTime.Date.AddDays(1).Add(allowedEnd) 
           : obj.EndDateTime <= obj.EndDateTime.Date.Add(allowedEnd)))) 
    {
        // valid
    } 
    else 
    {
        // invalid
    }
```

Comment: Try comparing against times, you are comparing dates.   Try using `obj.StartDateTime.Date.Add(allowedStart).TimeOfDay`.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of valid and invalid dates?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya People are only allowed to do certain things from for example 6am to 10pm and if received dates are not within those hours a warning has to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from single `value`

```
private static bool WithinSpan(DateTime value, TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to) =>
  value >= value.Date.Add(from) && value <= value.Date.Add(to);
```

Now we can implement the same with two `value`s:

```
private static bool WithinSpan(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate,
                               TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to) =>
// startDate <= endDate &&  // you may want to add this condition as well 
   startDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) && startDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to) &&
     endDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) &&   endDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to);
```

**Demo:**

```
  TimeSpan allowedStart = new TimeSpan(08, 00, 0);
  TimeSpan allowedEnd = new TimeSpan(20, 00, 0);

  (DateTime, DateTime)[] tests = new (DateTime, DateTime)[] {
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 10, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 20, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 50, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 15, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 10, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 35, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 23, 50, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 31,  0, 35, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 31,  7, 50, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 31,  8, 15, 0)),
  };

  Func<DateTime, DateTime, string> within = 
    (t1, t2) => $"{(WithinSpan(t1, t2, allowedStart, allowedEnd) ? "Yes" : "No")}";

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test.Item1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} .. {test.Item2:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} : {within(test.Item1, test.Item2)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
2020-01-30 19:10:00 .. 2020-01-30 19:20:00 : Yes
2020-01-30 19:50:00 .. 2020-01-30 20:15:00 : No
2020-01-30 20:10:00 .. 2020-01-30 20:35:00 : No
2020-01-30 23:50:00 .. 2020-01-31 00:35:00 : No
2020-01-31 07:50:00 .. 2020-01-31 08:15:00 : No
```

**Edit:**

Elaborated version is

```
private static bool WithinSpan(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate,
                               TimeSpan from, TimeSpan to) {
  // Empty Period
  if (startDate > endDate)
    return false;

  // [from..to] within single day
  if (to >= from)
    return startDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) && startDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to) &&
           endDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) && endDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to);

  // [from..midnight..to]
  if (startDate.Day == endDate.Day)
    return startDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) || endDate <= endDate.Date.Add(to);
  else {
    to = to.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

    return startDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) && startDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to) &&
           endDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) && endDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to);
  }
}
```

which removes empty periods, and treats `from > to` `TimeSpan` as containing midnight.

**Demo:**

```
  // from 22:00 to midnight and then up to 06:00
  TimeSpan allowedStart = new TimeSpan(22, 00, 00);
  TimeSpan allowedEnd   = new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00);

  (DateTime, DateTime)[] tests = new (DateTime, DateTime)[] {
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 10, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 20, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 19, 50, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 15, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 10, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 20, 35, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 23, 50, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 31,  0, 35, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 23, 00, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30, 23, 35, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 30,  3, 00, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 30,  4, 00, 0)),
    (new DateTime(2020, 1, 31,  4, 50, 0), new DateTime(2020, 1, 31,  8, 15, 0)),
  };

  Func<DateTime, DateTime, string> within =
    (t1, t2) => $"{(WithinSpan(t1, t2, allowedStart, allowedEnd) ? "Yes" : "No")}";

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test.Item1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} .. {test.Item2:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} : {within(test.Item1, test.Item2)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
2020-01-30 19:10:00 .. 2020-01-30 19:20:00 : No
2020-01-30 19:50:00 .. 2020-01-30 20:15:00 : No
2020-01-30 20:10:00 .. 2020-01-30 20:35:00 : No
2020-01-30 23:50:00 .. 2020-01-31 00:35:00 : Yes
2020-01-30 23:00:00 .. 2020-01-30 23:35:00 : Yes
2020-01-30 03:00:00 .. 2020-01-30 04:00:00 : Yes
2020-01-31 04:50:00 .. 2020-01-31 08:15:00 : No
```

**Next Edit:**
Shortened verison that magically works:

```
if (startDate > endDate) {
  return false;
}
if (startDate.Day == endDate.Day && to < from) {
  return startDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) || endDate <= endDate.Date.Add(to);
}
if (to < from) {
  to = to.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
}
return startDate >= startDate.Date.Add(from) && endDate <= startDate.Date.Add(to);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does successfully check if the start and end date are valid.

Comment: What if you start from 20:00:01 and go to 08:00:01? Start and end both are valid then but you spent the whole night within a forbidden timerange?

Comment: @Zeta: that's why I've commented: `// startDate <= endDate &&  // you may want to add this condition as well`. Uncomment this code if you want to remove empty periods

Comment: If the allowed timespan is 22:00 to 6:00 and you enter from 1am to 3am this leads to problems again :/ but I'm sure I'll find a way to fix that

Comment: @Zeta: the easiest way IMHO is to modify `allowedEnd` (see my edit)

Comment: This allows to use dates starting from the previous day that are ending on the next one, but the example from 1am to 3am still doesn't work for me

Comment: @Zeta: OK, let's have an elaborated version (please, see my edit).

Comment: Thank you very much, your version worked perfectly. I was able to remove some of the conditions that were used multiple times (what considerably made the method more readable). I added my final version as an edit if you want to have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Following, is the exact piece of code I use, for this not exact goal, in my program:

```
public bool IsInsideTimeframe(DateTime firstStart, DateTime firstEnd, DateTime secondStart, DateTime secondEnd)
{
    bool isInside;

    if (firstStart.Ticks >= secondStart.Ticks && firstEnd.Ticks <= secondEnd.Ticks)
        isInside = true;
    else
        isInside = false;

    return isInside;
}
```

Let's say you have two time frames, one between 11:00-14:00, the second is 10:00-15:00. In order to check whether the first timespan is inside the second, you use the function in following way:
IsInsideTimeframe(11:00, 14:00, 10:00, 15:00)

You can simply run this function on both of the dates you wish to validate, with the "allowed time span" as the "second" date given.